# Generated Thumbnails on some Windows installations overruled by icon of associated program

Tags: windows, view, icons, directory

I have written a Windows thumbnail handler for specific file types.  I have two pc's running Windows 7 Enterprise.  On one pc everything goes well.  On the other pc, the thumbnail generation works only when there is no program associated  with the file extension.  In that case the thumbnail generation is taken over by the associated program (I see an icon).  Changing the associated program (e.g. to Notepad++) changes the icon.  I suspect this to be a registry setting, or a folder view option, but I have no idea where to start looking.
Answers appreciated.

Comment: It's most likely a registry setting and there's some options with powershell [1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-associate-file-3898f323) [2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/01/06/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-modify-registry-settings-that-configure-windows-explorer/) to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It was a registry setting indeed.  Deleting some file association keys fixed the issue.  I have been trying to nail the issue down, but now I cannot reproduce the bad situation.